# Let $T \in \mathcal L (E)$. Then $\|T^3\|^2 \le \|T^2\|^3 \, \|T\|^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$. Let $\| \cdot\|$ be the operator norm on $\mathcal L(E)$.

I'm trying to solve Brezis' *exercise 6.23.2* where the author provides a hint. A special case of the hint can be stated as

> Let $T \in \mathcal L (E)$. Then $\|T^3\|^2 \le \|T^2\|^3 \, \|T\|^2$.

Could you provide me some hints (not the full solution) on how to prove above statement?

---

**Update:** Below is a screenshot of the hint.

[image]

Comment: If you take $E=\mathbb R$ with its unique norm, then $\mathcal L(E) = \mathbb R$ and the operator norm $\|.\|_{\infty}$ is just the normal absolute value. In that case, if $T=1/2$, the left-hand side of your inequality is $1/2^6$ while the right-hand side is $1/2^8$, so something appears to be wrong. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: It seems like the hint should instead be 
$$
\|T^3\|^2 \leq \|T^2\|^2 \|T\|^2.
$$
Otherwise, we could disprove the statement by taking $T = \alpha I$ for $\alpha > 0$ and $I$ denoting the identity operator.

Comment: @krm2233 I have just updated my post with the screenshot of the hint.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have just updated my post with the screenshot of the hint.

Comment: It is trivial that $\left\Vert T^{3}\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert T^{2}\right\Vert \left\Vert T\right\Vert $.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I don't get how your inequality helps...

Comment: What is the reason of the downvote???

Comment: The 'total power' on the two sides have to match. You have a total power of $6$ on LHS and $8$ on RHS. Such an inequality can never holds. (Forget about FA and Operator Theory).  To get a counter-example you just have to take $T$ to be a rea; number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that the following hints are not too much for your liking.

1. It seems that the "$\frac nm$" within the hint is really supposed to be $q$, i.e. $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$. Plugging $n = 3, m = 2, r = 1$ into *this version* of the equation from the hint, when cast in terms of the original operator, becomes the following:
   $$
   \log(\|T^3\|) \leq \lfloor3/2\rfloor \log(\|T^2\|) + \log(\|T\|) \iff\\
   \log(\|T^3\|) \leq \log(\|T^2\|) + \log(\|T\|) \iff\\
   \|T^3\| \leq \|T^2\| \cdot \|T\|,
   $$
   which is straightforward to see.
2. The fact that $a_n \leq \lfloor n/m\rfloor a_m + a_r$ can be deduced as a direct consequence of the fact $a_{i+j} \leq a_i + a_j$

Comment: The question is clearly wrong. See the comment by krm2233.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, I address the fact that the question is wrong by suggesting exactly how the typo in the question should be corrected