# How to prove that $(\frac{a_n}{n})_n$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a real Banach space and $T \in \mathcal L (E)$. Let
> $$
> a_n := \log \|T^n\|
> \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
> $$
>
> 1. Check that $a_{n+m} \le a_n + a_m$ for all $m, n \ge 1$.
> 2. Deduce that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ exists and coincides with $\inf_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n}$. [[Hint:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745566/let-t-in-mathcal-l-e-then-t3-2-le-t2-3-t-2) Fix an integer $m \geq 1$. Given any integer $n \geq 1$ write $n=m q+r$, where $q$ is the largest integer $\le \frac{n}{m}$ and $0 \leq r<m$. Note that $a_n \leq q a_m+a_r$.]

From the author's hint, I got that $\frac{a_n}{n} \le a_1$ for all $n \ge 1$. I could not even prove that $(\frac{a_n}{n})_n$ is bounded from below. Could you provide me with some more hints (not the full solution) on how to prove that $(\frac{a_n}{n})_n$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: There are difficulties of definition for any $n$ satisfying $T^n = 0$ (and this is definitely possible for nonzero $T$), which may relate to your inability to prove the sequence is bounded from below.  In any event [and spoiler alert], does this answer your question? [Subadditive Sequence Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556630/subadditive-sequence-convergence)

Comment: Hint: for showing that the lim equals the inf (possibly equal to $-∞$), it suffices to show that for fixed $m ∈ ℕ$,  $ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} \leq \frac{a_m}{m}.$

Comment: The convergence of subadditive sequences is a result by Fekete (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4548553/121671)).